# Porque sale error el return y con get no?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, clase

Intento devolver un picturebox y me comentó el profesor que hay que hacerlo con return en vez de un get, ya que get se usa para las propiedades y esto se trata de un método.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me salta ningún error ¿qué estoy haciendo mal para que con return no me salte un error? Gracias.

Comment: parece que faltan los parentesis

Comment: querias declarar un metodo o una propiedad??? si es un metodo, le faltan parentesis.. y se devuelve con return.. si es una propiedad, la segunda la escribiste bien.. y para la proxima, no uses imagenes... tu codigo y errores debe ir como texto...

Comment: sisi, es un método, que parentesis faltan ?

Comment: y.. si es un metodo, debe estar definida como un metodo.. los parentesis despues de EnviarImagen (public PictureBox EnviarImagen() )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para recuperar o definir el valor de una propiedad necesitas como lo indica el error un "descriptor de acceso":

```
  public PictureBox EnviarImagen
     {
         get { return cajaImagen; }
         set { cajaImagen = value; }
     }
```

o también

```
  public PictureBox EnviarImagen
     {
         get => cajaImagen; }
         set => cajaImagen = value; }
     }
```

Si deseas definir un método que regrese el valor del PictureBox lo debes realizar de esta forma:

```
public PictureBox EnviarImagen()
     {
         return cajaImagen;
     }
```